# Php, ошибка при использовании preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
  if (preg_match ("/^[a-zа-я0-9_]{3,15}$/", $_POST['reg_name'], $_POST['reg_pass'])) {
      /*последующий код, где имя и захешированный пароль заносятся в бд*/
     }
```

Проблема в том, что пароль не записывается в бд. Но если писать вот так:

```
if (strlen($_POST['reg_name']) >= 3 and strlen($_POST['reg_pass']) >= 3 {}
```

То всё работает. Но, конечно же, мне желательна проверка.

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста

Comment: надо или `preg_match("/^[a-zа-я0-9_]{3,15}$/", $_POST['reg_name'])` или `preg_match("/^[a-zа-я0-9_]{3,15}$/", $_POST['reg_pass'])` Но не одновременно два, как у вас.

Comment: @Эдуард так вот в чём дело) Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: почитать можно здесь: [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Если вы используете русские буквы, добавьте модификатор `u`. Если нужна поддержка заглавных и прописных букв, добавьте модификатор `i` - `$regex = "/^[a-zа-яё0-9_]{3,15}$/iu"` (`ё` добавлено). И, как уже было сказано, должно быть 2 `preg_match`, `if (preg_match($regex, $_POST['reg_name']) and preg_match($regex, $_POST['reg_pass'])) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание на сигнатуру [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php):

> `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )`

`$subject` — это `string`, а `$_POST['reg_pass']` у вас передаётся как массив для сохранения найденного соответствия.

Нужно поправить регулярное выражение, добавить `ё` и модификаторы `iu` для работы со строками Юникода (`u`) и регистронезависимого поиска (`i`), а затем использовать конструкцию типа `if (preg_match(...) && preg_match(...)) {...}`:

```
$regex = "/^[a-zа-яё0-9_]{3,15}$/iu";
if (preg_match($regex, $_POST['reg_name']) && preg_match($regex, $_POST['reg_pass']))
{
    // Добавить в базу
}
```

Comment: я бы ещё порекомендовал почитать про фильтры. тут как раз нужен на валидацию http://php.net/filter

Comment: @Lexx918 Можно попробовать и с `preg_grep`, но в данном случае, можно обойтись двумя `preg_match`. Тут [PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/GTVZem).